# Web server in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, database

I am new to linux server development. I want to create a webserver for our college so that it can be accessed by everyone over internet in our android app.
      Anyone please answer whether i can access data in our server remotely on internet through android app.
     Please explain in ubuntu os.

Comment: This question is very broad and hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes you can.

You will need to decide what stack you want to use as there is lots of choice, eg you can use Apache or Nginx as examples of webservers, and MariaDB or PostgreSQL as examples of databases.

How you interact with your android app will depend on which stack you choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache server for example. It requires some advanced knowledge of the commands as well as some patience though.
It is quite easy in general to configure a Webserver to run in Ubuntu. Apache however, can be configured in multiple ways in order to serve the requests of many domains. It can also encrypt communications (via HTTPS) and secure websites using various types of authentication.
Since Apache is available in the default software repositories of Ubuntu, you can install it like any other package using package management tools. You may want for example to follow this [link](https://net2.com/how-to-install-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu/) for a detailed step by step instructions. Let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you think.

Don't use a server in your college. Rent/purchase time in a "virtual private server" (aka VPS) with a cloud provider. This is quite cheap these days for low CPU/network usage (I pay mine $6/month).

By doing so, if the server is hacked (always a possibility for something facing the internet) the damage is restricted to the server. If the server is in your college network, 1) you have to give access from the internet to your college network (and make sure that only the right machines are accessible, and this is technically complicated (firewalls, DMZ...)) and 2) if the server is hacked the hackers will likely find an access to other machines on the college network.

Once you have the VPS you can install a "stack" (the set of software necessary to run the server) often "LAMP" (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP), but can be something else, basically:

- One operating system (Linux is free and well suited for the task, there are distros designed for servers, such as Ubuntu Server).
- A web server, that gets the requests and either returns static content (HTML, Images...) or passes the bucket to some application code. The two popular choices are Apache and Nginx (both free).
- A database (because this is the best way to implement persistence of your data), MySQL/MariaDB or PostgresSQL being free and popular).
- Possibly some support for the application code: PHP or Python run by themselves, Java usually requires a server runtime (Tomcat)

The cloud provider will often provide pre-installed machines with decent shielding against hackers.

You add to this your server application (custom-made code, or some software package that runs over said stack)(possibly the part that is going to take the more time anyway).

You may also need to purchase a domain name (`ourcollege.edu`) if you college has not got one already and seed the relevant DNS servers so that they resolve `server.ourcollege.edu` to your VPS address.

This said, to be honest, if you have to ask this question here, this is going to be a uphill battle because you likely haven't got the necessary skills yet.